# Why is my Simpson's modelling not giving the correct answer?

Tags: python, numerical-integration, simpsons-rule

I've been trying to do some Simpson's modelling to approximate integrals and although my code runs fine, it doesn't seem to give the correct answer. I'm new-ish to coding so I understand it's probably a dumb mistake but I can't figure out what's wrong. f(x) has already been defined and seems to work, it's just this integral approximation that's a bit dodgey.

```
def integrate_numeric(xmin, xmax, N):
    ''' 
    Numerical integral of f from xmin to xmax using Simpson's rule with 
        N panels.
    '''
    h = (xmax - xmin)/2*N
   
    # Odd sum
    oddtotal = 0
    for i in range(1, N, 2):
        oddtotal += f(xmin + (i*h))
    f_odd = oddtotal
    
    # Even sum
    eventotal = 0
    for i in range(2, N, 2):
        eventotal += f(xmin + (i*h))
    f_even = eventotal
    
    return (h/3)*(f(xmin)+(4*f_odd)+(2*f_even)+f(xmax))
```

Comment: Which answer does it give and which answer would be correct?

Comment: Are the values of h, f_odd, and f_even correct?

Comment: It gives 0.66 when it should give -8.5242, so it's way off

Comment: For which f, xmin, xmax and N is this? Can you please show a [mre]?

Comment: Possibly not, it's my first time trying Simpson's modeeling. I'm reasonably confident in h though and I intended to do it so that f_odd is f(xmin+(h * odd integers)) up to N and similarly for f_even (but this time with even integers)

Comment: `def f(x):
    return numpy.cos(2*x)*x**2` and between 0 and 4 for N=1 is what I've been testing

Answer (score 1):

- The ranges for odd numbers need to be from x=1 to x=N-1
- The ranges for even numbers need to be from x=2 to x=N-2
- h is needs to be (xmax - xmin)/N

Here is the Simpsons rule, with those corrections:

```
def f(x):
    return x**2


def integrate_numeric(xmin, xmax, N):
    '''
    Numerical integral of f from xmin to xmax using Simpson's rule with
        N panels.
    '''
    h = (xmax - xmin) / N

    odd_sum = sum(f(xmin + i*h) for i in range(1, N, 2))
    even_sum = sum(f(xmin + i*h) for i in range(2, N-1, 2))

    return h/3 * (f(xmin) + 4*odd_sum + 2*even_sum + f(xmax))


print(integrate_numeric(0, 10, 50)) -> 333.3333333333333
```

Alternatively, just use [scipy's simpsons rule](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simpson.html)